# ANTLR grammar to match the comment lines started with #

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am trying to match below text with an ANTLR grammar:

[image]

The ANTLR grammar is:

```
grammar header;


start : commentBlock
        EOF;

commentBlock : CommentLine+;
CommentLine  : '#' AsciiChars+;
AsciiChars : [a-zA-Z];

fragment CR : '\r';
fragment LF : '\n';
EOL : CR?LF ->skip;

fragment Tab : '\t';
fragment Space : ' ';
TS : (Tab|Space)+ ->skip;
```

The error I got is:

```
line 1:0 token recognition error at: '# '
line 2:0 token recognition error at: '# '
line 3:0 token recognition error at: '# '
[@0,2:2='a',<AsciiChars>,1:2]
[@1,7:7='b',<AsciiChars>,2:2]
[@2,12:12='c',<AsciiChars>,3:2]
[@3,15:14='<EOF>',<EOF>,4:0]
line 1:2 mismatched input 'a' expecting CommentLine
```

I guess the grammar is reasonable, but why the error is happening?

### ADD 1

Strange, after I changed the **lexer** rule `CommentLine` into a **parser** rule `commentLine`, it works:

```
grammar header;

start : commentBlock
        EOF;

commentBlock : commentLine+;
commentLine  : '#' AsciiChars+; // <=== here CommentLine -> commentLine
AsciiChars : [a-zA-Z];

fragment CR : '\r';
fragment LF : '\n';
EOL : CR?LF ->skip;

fragment Tab : '\t';
fragment Space : ' ';
TS : (Tab|Space)+ ->skip;
```

But actually I want to discard all the comment lines. If it has to be a parser rule, I cannot use `->skip` to discard it.

### ADD 2

I think I can explain it now.

The critial things to remember are:

- lexer phase happens before parser phase.
- If a **skipped** token T1 is referenced by another lexer rule, say token T2, the token T1 part **within** token T2 will **not** be skipped.

Let me explain it with a concise example:

The document to match:

```
#   abc
```

Grammar 1:

```
grammar test;

t : T2;
p : t
    EOF;

Char : [a-z];

T2 : '#' T1+ Char+; // <<<< Here T2 reference the so-skipped T1.

fragment Tab : '\t';
fragment Space : ' ';
T1 : (Tab|Space)+ ->skip; //<<<<< T1 is to be skipped.
```

In grammar 1, T1 is skipped, but the T1 part in T2 is not skipped. T2 will match the input text in the lexer phase. (Even we put the T2 after T1, T2 will still match. I think ANTLR did some greedy match to match for the longest token.)

Grammar 2:

The skipped T1 is not referenced by another token rule, but directly in a parser rule.

```
grammar test;

t : '#' T1+ Char+; // <<<<<<<<<<<< HERE
p : t
    EOF;

Char : [a-z];

fragment Tab : '\t';
fragment Space : ' ';
T1 : (Tab|Space)+ ->skip; //<<<<< T1 is to be skipped.
```

This time, **no T2 rule to help the spaces to survive the lexer phase**, all T1 in the input file will be skipped. So **when in the parser phase afterwards**, the matching will fail with this error:

```
[@0,0:0='#',<'#'>,1:0]
[@1,4:4='a',<Char>,1:4]
[@2,5:5='b',<Char>,1:5]
[@3,6:6='c',<Char>,1:6]
[@4,7:6='<EOF>',<EOF>,1:7]
line 1:4 mismatched input 'a' expecting T1
```

Because all T1 are already **discarded in lexer phase**.

### ADD 3

Back to my original question, the subtle mistake I made is, I thought after the `TS` is skipped, the remaining characters can be **re-grouped** into the new token `CommentLine`, which has no spaces. This is plain wrong with ANTLR.

Because [lexer phase all happens before parser phase](http://antlr.1301665.n2.nabble.com/lexer-s-rule-overlapping-problem-td3593205.html), the `CommentLine` is a token rule, it has no spaces in it, so it won't match anything in the input content.

So just as @macmoonshine said, I do have to add `TS` into the `CommentLine` token.

Comment: Be sure to check out the many options I suggest below.

Comment: Surely there's an "Accept" in there somewhere -- what else can I help with to get an Accept ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grammar does not include spaces in comments, but your comments does.

EDIT: Have you tried `commentLine  : '#' TS AsciiChars;` as comment rule?

Comment: Thanks, but I did match all spaces with `TS` and dumped them with `->skip`. This happens in the lexical phase which is prior to parser phase. So I think I don't need to specify spaces in my parser rules.

Comment: Your comment rule is a `#` followed by ASCII characters, and the `TS` rule isn't included. ANTLR states `'# '` (a `#` and a space) as error.

Comment: I tried. The error change to `missing TS`. I guess it's because I have dumped them in lexical phase. So parser phase won't see it.

Comment: Put the `TS` rule in front of the comment rule.

Comment: I put the `TS` rule prior to `commentBlock` and `commentLine` rules. Still the `missing TS` error.

Comment: You could also include spaces in the comment rule `commentLine  : '#' [ A-Za-z]*;`, which should allow spaces inside of comments as well.

Comment: You nailed the root cause. I finally thought it through. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for :

```
grammar Header;

start : CommentLine+ EOF;

CommentLine  : '#' ' ' AsciiChars+;
AsciiChars : [a-zA-Z];

fragment CR : '\r';
fragment LF : '\n';
EOL : CR?LF ->skip;

fragment Tab : '\t';
fragment Space : ' ';
TS : (Tab|Space)+ ->skip;
```

Now this one uses just a lexer rule.

### TO IGNORE COMMENTS

```
grammar Header;

start : CommentLine+ EOF;

CommentLine  : '#' ' ' AsciiChars+ -> skip;
AsciiChars : [a-zA-Z];

fragment CR : '\r';
fragment LF : '\n';
EOL : CR?LF ->skip;

fragment Tab : '\t';
fragment Space : ' ';
TS : (Tab|Space)+ ->skip;
```

This will ignore the commments entirely, and in fact gives an error as written because the rule `'start` expects a `CommentLine` which now is discarded.  So if you want to **ignore and discard** comments, use something like this second one and don't make mention of `CommentLine` in your parser rules, just let the lexer strip them.  Or if you want to preserve comments, you can use the previous one.

### TO REROUTE COMMENTS

A final idea is to reroute comments to another channel:

```
grammar Header;

start : other EOF;
other: AsciiChars;
CommentLine  : '#' ' ' AsciiChars+ -> channel(2);
AsciiChars : [a-zA-Z]+;

fragment CR : '\r';
fragment LF : '\n';
EOL : CR?LF ->skip;

fragment Tab : '\t';
fragment Space : ' ';
TS : (Tab|Space)+ ->skip;
```

In this grammar, comments are still lexed, but routed to another channel for possible processing.  And I added another rule in 
`start` just so there'd be something to match in:

```
# a
# b
something
# c

[@0,0:2='# a',<CommentLine>,channel=2,1:0]
[@1,5:7='# b',<CommentLine>,channel=2,2:0]
[@2,10:18='something',<AsciiChars>,3:0]
[@3,21:23='# c',<CommentLine>,channel=2,4:0]
[@4,26:25='<EOF>',<EOF>,5:0]
```

One of these options should surely do it for you ;)

Comment: This should work I think. But I just don't know why changing a lexer rule `CommentLine` to a parser rule `commentLine` can make it work? Actually I want to discard all the comment. If it has to be a parser rule, I cannot use `->skip` with it.

Comment: You don't have to use a parser rule that matches.  You can simply ignore it in the Listener or Visitor.  There are other ways of doing this though, give me a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  It appears your comment is the same as a normal single line comment with the `'#'` swapped for `'//'`.  If you require a space after the hash use: `'# '`.  If you require the hash to be in column 1 use: `[\n\r] '# ' ~[\n\r]`.  From looking at the example this should cover all the potential options.

```
COMMENT_LINE
    : '#'  ~[\n\r]* ->( skip )
    ;
```